# Многопоточность Java

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня есть такой класс

```
public class MyClass implements Runnable {

private Boolean flag = false;

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (flag) {
                try {
                    stop();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                flag = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void stop() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Sleeeep");
    }

    public void setFlag(Boolean flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }
}
```

И вот такой класс с методом main

```
public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        MyClass m1 = new MyClass();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(m1);
        t1.start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            m1.setFlag(true);
        }
    }
}
```

как правильно сделать чтобы метод `stop` класса `MyClass` выполнился 10 раз?

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос. Добавьте в `run` счетчик перед `stop()`, а в условии цикла проверяйте не достиг ли он 10.

Answer (score 3):

Решил свой вопрос сам. Надо было создать объект для мониторинга

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        MyClass m1 = new MyClass();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(m1);
        t1.start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            synchronized(m1.obj) {
                m1.setFlag(true);
                m1.obj.wait();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

И класс MyClass

```
public class MyClass implements Runnable {

    private Boolean flag = false;
    public final Object obj = new Object();

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (flag) {
                synchronized(obj) {
                    try {
                        stop();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    flag = false;
                    obj.notify();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void stop() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Sleeeep");
    }

    public void setFlag(Boolean flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }
}
```

Comment: Достаточно было объявить переменную `flag` как `volatile`.

Comment: и ничего бы не изменилось

Comment: А, ну да. Неверно понял условие задачи. В любом случае